# How to move everything in Graphics2D by x,y coordinates.

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I need to move already made BufferedImage by x,y coordinates and then draw another things on it with Graphics2D object. I tried to use this code to do that :

```
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.translate(x, y);
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any way to move everything in Graphics2D object and then draw on it or I have to use this code to do that:

```
BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = temp.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img,x, y,null);
```

Using this code and then drawing only few elements rather than making whole image from scratch isn't big leap in performance so I think making new BufferedImage then drawing image on it isn't best way. I would rather just create Graphics2D object from already made image and then just move it by a few pixels diagonally, but I couldn't find the way to do that.

Comment: Instead of creating a temp image, did you try to just paint it onto itself (ie. using `img.createGraphics().drawImage(img, x, y, null)`)? In any case, it sounds like it would be better to just leave the original image as is, and do the translation when painting to the screen. But it's hard to say what you ultimately try to achieve here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Graphics2d docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate(int,%20int)) when you use translate:

> All coordinates used in **subsequent** rendering operations on this graphics context are relative to this new origin.

You are defining a transformation that affects future operations. After calling translate if you were to call a method on graphics like `draw3DRect(0, 0, ... snipped ... )` the starting coordinates 0,0 would be translated by x,y.

I think your best bet might be to use the methods of BufferedImage to move all the pixels before you get the graphics object. You have [getRgb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)) and [setRgb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int))

A naive example of moving the pixels:

```
BufferedImage buffImg = ImageIO.read(img);
int width = buffImg.getWidth();
int horizontalOffset = 10;
int verticalOffset = 10;
int widthToMove = width - horizontalOffset;
int heightToMove = buffImg.getHeight() - verticalOffset;
int[] rgb = buffImg.getRGB(0, 0, widthToMove, heightToMove, null, 0, widthToMove);
buffImg.setRGB(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,widthToMove, heightToMove,rgb, 0, widthToMove);
```

This still leaves you with some work to do because there is a strip at the top and to the left that you need to fill with background colour.

If it's going to be used on big images you might want to use a buffer int[] and pass it to getRGB in a loop, getting and setting in chunks.